# getActionBar() returns NULL in actionBar

Tags: java, android, object, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I am currently creating the `actionBar` in android studio and I have created action buttons and my aim is to have a dropdown menu everytime I click a button.

In my *menu_main.xml*, I added the items search and help:

```
        <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/action_help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
        android:title="@string/action_help"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

In my *MainActivity.java*, I have added the Strings for my dropdown:

```
    String[] actions = new String[] {
            "Bookmark", "Subscribe", "Share", "Like"
    };
```

In my `onOptionsItemSelected()` method, i have added the case where everytime you click on this button, it will call a function. Here is my code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_help:
                helpMessage();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

        private void helpMessage() {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Location button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, actions);
            System.out.println("HERE: " + getActionBar());
            getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
            ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected : " + actions[itemPosition], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            };
            getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);
        }
```

When I run the program, my app will crash and I get

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.app.ActionBar.setNavigationMode(int)' on a null object
>   reference

It points to `getActionBar()` which is NULL.
Any thoughts?

Comment: What activity your class extends?

Comment: Hello. It extends `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: Make sure the setContentView(view) has been already called for your Activity, otherwise getActionBar() will return null.

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` is already called but `getActionBar()` still returns null

Comment: Make sure you have not styled your application or activity as Theme.NOTITLE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always have this error....
I found a solution which I put this to my `Style` it will be work and `getActionBar()` won't be null anymore...

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

Use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`. Also theme of your activity should be extended of `Theme.AppCompat`.

Comment: Thanks! But I have tried this one and doesn't work, unfortunately. The app still crashes.

Comment: Do you know why `getActionBar()` returns null?

Comment: Try to extend AppCompatActivity, maybe it will help you. I've just launched it without crash with activity extended from `AppCompatActiivity` and `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: I changed my extends to `AppCompatActivity` and used `getSupportActionBar()`, but in my `setListNavigationCallbacks()`, I need to cast the `navigationListener`, so I casted it. Then there is 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.marananld.finalactionbar.MainActivity$1 cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.ActionBar$OnNavigationListener`

Comment: Actually this method was deprecated in API level 21, so, it is better for you to use up-to-date navigation patterns. But if you still want to use this, you should provide correct navigation listener to this method. You can simply make your activity to implement ActionBar.OnNavigationListener interface, and implement correct methods, then pass `MainActivity.this` as navigation listener

Answer (score 0):

I think you should
1.Check themes

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

2.Check your Activity class , it's extend AppcombatActivity or ActionBarActivity

So, I hope it useful for you